# FLASK: curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5500: Connection refused

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to transition from making Rshiny apps to flask-react apps. Its definitely a steep learning curve so far!

I am sort of following a few tutorials e.g (https://dev.to/arnu515/build-a-fullstack-twitter-clone-using-flask-and-react-1j72) to try and get some basic functionality down .

However some reason curl can't seem to interact with my app. I've tried putting the urls with and without quotes but get the same response. Also I tried the default 5000 port as well. I am running the app in windows:

```
C:\Users\Marc\flaskTest\backend>curl "http://127.0.0.1:5500"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5500: Connection refused
```

app.py code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello"
    
@app.route('/message', methods=["GET"])
def message():
    message ="my message"
    return jsonify({"message": message})
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `jsonify` in the view function but haven't imported it before, so there would be error when Flask app runs.

Actually you can just write code like `return {"message": message}`, it would do the same thing with `jsonify` does if you are using latest version of flask.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5500)
```

Also in windows cmd type `ipconfig` IPV4 address. Suppose your IPV4 address is 192.168.X.X, access the website as `http://192.168.X.X:5500`.

Read what it does: [Externally Visible Server](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#public-server)